# In Symfony 1.2 (PHP), how to add validation to admin generated controlpanel?

Tags: validation, forms, symfony1

I have created module ( test ) having following structure within control panel application:

- config
- actions ( contains generator.yml)
- templates

I have used admin generator to generate the control panel. How can I add validation to the form displayed in control panel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will have to setup the validation inside the configure method of your form.

read more about here: http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_2/en/02-Form-Validation

you will find all forms in /lib/form/